# Need to run api on same path nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, nginx-location

I need to run multiple https urls on single domain

Here is my nginx file. I ran front-end with the below settings on `https`. Now my dashboard is running on `https` and my api are on `http`.

```
server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate bundle_chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key mykey.key;
  server_name my_domin.com;
  location / { 
       proxy_pass my_host:port;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Now obviously it cannot hit on https to http. So I want to run api's on https by changing the above configuration.(I don't have wild-card ssl)

How can I do that. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you put an example on how you request the api? it's api.my_domain.com ? is it my_domain.com/api ? With more info I can help you better (or tell you alternatives on what to do).

Comment: @flaixman Thank you for the reply. Actually I have only domain ssl and I have installed it on my frontend using the above configuration. Now I don't have the wildcard But I need to run my api's as well. Can I do that using single domain ssl nginx ? Please help

Comment: Ho, that's where you are wrong, you can hit your api through http even when the connection comes from https. That's what a reverse proxy_pass does. If you listen to port80 on "my_host" configuration, make your api read x-forwarded-proto instead of scheme. It would be different if it was a redirect, but you can https to http if you use a proxy pass. It doesn't show any error on the client side, because he makes a connextion http to my_domain.com, and then you make whatever you want with that connection, which the client doesn't know. If you make a proxy_pass to yourself, you can do it http.